# Problem with indexOf in an array of objects. React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a following situation where I want to know the indexOf value to be able to use that knowledge later on in the code. How ever, I've tried multiple different ways to get the value and I don't seem to get it right. In the code below I've tried a few different ways that I found searching Stackoverflow. All of them return -1 so far, meaning that there is either something wrong with my code or some other issue I'm not able to find at the moment.

FYI, selectedGroup is an array with objects inside, just like this:
`[{label: "somelabel", value: 100}]`
and there can be many of them, depends on the user.

code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const GroupButtonMaker = ({ selectedGroup}) => {
  const [newButtons, setNewButtons] = useState([]);
  console.log(newButtons);

  useEffect(() => {
    const createButtons = () => {
      setNewButtons(
        selectedGroup.map(item => {
          return (
            <button
              id={item.value}
              className={'btn green micro'}
              key={item.value}
              onClick={event => btnHandler(event)}
            >
              {item.label}
            </button>
          );
        })
      );
    };
    createButtons();
  }, [selectedGroup]);

  const btnHandler = event => {
//here at the handler I'm trying multiple different ways to find indexOf as a test. No luck so far. 
    const eventID = event.currentTarget.id;
    let currentTargetIndex = newButtons
      .map(item => item.value)
      .indexOf(eventID);
    console.log(currentTargetIndex);
    console.log(newButtons.findIndex(x => x.value === eventID));
  };

  Array.prototype.indexOfObject = function arrayObjectIndexOf(property, value) {
    for (var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; i++) {
      if (this[i][property] === value) return i;
    }
    return -1;
  };
// here i've hardcored one value as a test to see if it works but it didn't so far.
  console.log(newButtons.indexOfObject('value', 107));

  const idx = newButtons.reduce(function(cur, val, index, eventID) {
    if (val.value === eventID && cur === -1) {
      return index;
    }
    return cur;
  }, -1);
  console.log(idx);

  return <ul>{newButtons.map(item => item)}</ul>;
};
export default GroupButtonMaker;
```

Thank you beforehand for any suggestions to my current problem. Hopefully I've managed to describe the problem in a way that makes it solveable. If not, please ask and I'll try to provide an answer.

Comment: At `newButtons.map(item => item.value)`, each `item` is a `<button>`, map with `.value` will return an array of `undefined`. You couldn't find `eventID` in an array of `undefined`, that's why it returned `-1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply pass the `id` of the button to the handler instead of getting it from `event`.

You can achieve it by this: `onClick={(event) => btnHandler(item.value)}`

And then in your `btnHandler`, just look up the index of the selected button from `selectedGroup` instead of `newButtons`.

Here, give this a try:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const GroupButtonMaker = ({ selectedGroup }) => {
  const [newButtons, setNewButtons] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const buttons = selectedGroup.map(item => {
      return (
        <button
          id={item.value}
          className={"btn green micro"}
          key={item.value}
          onClick={(event) => btnHandler(item.value)}
        >
          {item.label}
        </button>
      );
    });
    setNewButtons(buttons);
  }, [selectedGroup]);

  const btnHandler = buttonId => {
    const selectedButtonIndex = selectedGroup.findIndex(item => item.value === buttonId);
    console.log("selectedButtonIndex is: ", selectedButtonIndex);
  };
  return <ul>{newButtons.map(item => item)}</ul>;
};
export default GroupButtonMaker;
```

---

> Here's a [**Working Sample Code Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-selected-button-index) for your ref.

Comment: Thank you very much. You're indeed right, it works and fits for my purpose. I'll mark this as the right answer!